# Is there a way to fix AdBlocker on pause - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adblock

I have build in my React JS project an AdBlocker function to track if it is enabled or not  . It works fine like it spouse to be. When is activated i have created an pop up with a suggestion to disable it , but i wonder is there a way if the AdBlocker is paused for the current page the pop up shouldn't be dispalyed ? Any helpful tips are welcome

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AdBlockerDetection extends Component{

    state = {
        usingAdBlock : false,
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState ({
            usingAdBlock: this.fakeAdBanner.offsetHeight === 0 
        });
    }

    render(){
        if(this.state.usingAdBlock === true) {
            return this.props.children;
        }
        return(
            <div
                ref={r =>(this.fakeAdBanner = r)}
                style={{ 
                    height: '1px', 
                    width: '1px', 
                    visibility: 'none',
                    pointerEvents: 'none'
                }}
                className='adBanner'
         />
        );
    }
} 

export default AdBlockerDetection
```

Comment: How do you check if adblocker exists?

Comment: @MoshFeu i add a small bait to activate it if it exist

Comment: So, if the adblock is paused, it will not "eat" your bait and `this.state.usingAdBlock` will be `false`, isn't?

Comment: @MoshFeu exactly

Comment: So, I don't understand the issue. it should work out of the box when the extension is paused..

Comment: @MoshFeu . No it only works after the AdBlocker is tottaly **disabled** and not **paused**.

Comment: Seriously? How is different? If you check is built on adblocker to block your file (the "bait") and when the adblock is paused it doesn't block the file, why it's not enough?